# Incorrect input shape in coreml after converting keras model

Tags: python, ios, keras, coreml, coremltools

I have keras model like that:

```
inputlayer = Input(shape=(126,12))

model = BatchNormalization()(inputlayer)
model = Conv1D(16, 25, activation='relu')(model)
model = Flatten()(model)
model = Dense(output_size, activation='sigmoid')(model)

model = Model(inputs=inputlayer, outputs=model)
```

Which I convert to `coreml`:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model,
                                                    class_labels=classes)
coreml_model.save('speech_model.mlmodel')
```

So, I expect to see `MultiArray (Double 126x12)`, but I see `MultiArray (Double 12)`

[image]

Could you help to say what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: On the keras side, everything seems pretty ok.

Comment: Perhaps coremltools sees the 126 as the batch size. What happens when you convert the model _without_ the initial `BatchNormalization` layer?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [identified by G-mel](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/70) It appears that this bug happens because the input is length 2. CoreMLtools then assumes your input has shape `[Seq, D]`. You can get around this buy adding a reshape layer:

```
inputlayer = Input(shape=(126 * 12,))

model = Reshape((126,12))(inputlayer)
model = BatchNormalization()(model)
model = Conv1D(16, 25, activation='relu')(model)
model = Flatten()(model)
model = Dense(output_size, activation='sigmoid')(model)

model = Model(inputs=inputlayer, outputs=model)
```

Your app then has to flatten the input. This is not ideal however because it is not very efficient on the GPU. Hopefully the problem will soon be fixed.

Comment: I opened issue in coremltools and it they said that issue fixed, but I haven't check it yet

https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/70

Comment: @AndriiKrupka you are right. The source of the problem is not what I thought it was so I added the correct answer. Hopefully this will be fixed soon. because putting the reshape operation in the model is not ideal.